# Why does not work the use of an extension method in the same extension method?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, extension-methods, dynamic-programming, generic-programming

I got an extension method that gives me the value of every property in an instance. For scalar values works it fine. But for `Collections` there is a problem. This is my code:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToXml(Of T)(ByVal source As T) As XmlDocument
    Dim oXmlDocument As New XmlDocument
    oXmlDocument.AppendChild(oXmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", Nothing))
    oXmlDocument.AppendChild(oXmlDocument.CreateElement(XmlConvert.EncodeName(source.GetType.ToString)))

    For Each Item As System.Reflection.FieldInfo In source.GetType.GetFields
        Dim oElement As XmlElement = oXmlDocument.CreateElement(XmlConvert.EncodeName(Item.MemberType.ToString))
        oElement.Attributes.Append(oXmlDocument.CreateAttribute("Name")).Value = Item.Name
        oElement.Attributes.Append(oXmlDocument.CreateAttribute("Value")).Value = Item.GetValue(source)

        oXmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(oElement)
    Next

    For Each Item As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In source.GetType.GetProperties
        Dim oElement As XmlElement = oXmlDocument.CreateElement(XmlConvert.EncodeName(Item.MemberType.ToString))
        oElement.Attributes.Append(oXmlDocument.CreateAttribute("Name")).Value = Item.Name

        If (Not (TryCast(Item.GetValue(source, Nothing), ICollection) Is Nothing)) Then
            For Each SubItem As Object In CType(Item.GetValue(source, Nothing), ICollection)
                For Each Node As XmlNode In SubItem.ToXml().DocumentElement.SelectNodes("node()")
                    oElement.AppendChild(oElement.OwnerDocument.ImportNode(Node, True))
                Next
            Next
        Else
            oElement.Attributes.Append(oXmlDocument.CreateAttribute("Value")).Value = If(Not (Item.GetValue(source, Nothing) Is Nothing), Item.GetValue(source, Nothing).ToString, "Nothing")
        End If

        oXmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(oElement)
    Next

    Return oXmlDocument
End Function
```

The line

```
For Each Node As XmlNode In SubItem.ToXml().DocumentElement.SelectNodes("node()")
```

throws the error `Public member 'ToXml' on type 'MyClass' not found.`

But if I do

```
Dim instance As new MyClass
instance.ToXml()
```

this also works. Where is my fault in the loop?

Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.NET, extension methods don't work on variables declared as `Object` for backward compatibility.

Try:

```
Dim instance As Object = new MyClass()
instance.ToXml()
```

It will fail.

So you can't call `ToXml` on `SubItem` because `SubItem` is of type `Object`.

---

You can, however, just call `ToXml` like a regular method:

```
For Each Node As XmlNode In ToXml(SubItem).DocumentElement.SelectNodes("node()")
```